# Make Nested Async Functions Nested Sync Functions

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension that uses two nested async functions. However I wanted the functions to be sync, but there isn't a parameter that makes it sync, the API has only the async option. I need the two functions to have a nested sync functions behavior, if that is possible. Tell me if it makes any sense to you. Here is the main parts of the code:

```
// Track the number of callbacks from chrome.history.getVisits()
// that we expect to get.  When it reaches zero, we have all results.
chrome.history.search({
        'text': '',              // Return every history item....
        'startTime': oneWeekAgo,  // that was accessed less than one week ago.
        'maxResults': 999999999
    },
    function (historyItems) {
        // For each history item, get details on all visits.;

        for (var i = 0; i < historyItems.length; ++i) {
           Edited - 0 - I need some code here too.
           chrome.history.getVisits({url: historyItems[i].url}, function           (visitItems)   {
                //1 - I want this to happen first, but it happens after 2

                for (var j = 0; j < visitItems.length; ++j) {
                    //Do something that depends on the first function
                }
            })
            //2 -i want this to happen second and after 1, but it happens first, since chrome.history.getvisits is async.
        }
        //3- I want this to happen third, when the two loops are complete.
    })
```

Comment: While it's not possible to make things magically sync, you can do with [Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is inherently single-threaded, and "asynchronous" means "somewhere later in the event queue", really.

Because of that, there's no way to wait until an async task ends: you have to end running for the next async task to start. The only way is to add on code to be called at the end of the async task, known as async (or callback) chaining.

However, thankfully, there are frameworks that help you build this stuff in a more organized way. One such framework is [Promises](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/). I'll leave you to visit that link for a basic introduction.

First, let's "promisify" the required API calls. First one:

```
function historyLastWeek() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    chrome.history.search({
      'text': '',
      'startTime': oneWeekAgo, // don't forget that part
      'maxResults': 999999999
    }, function(historyItems) {
      if(chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        reject(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
      } else {
        resolve(historyItems);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

The above code returns a Promise, that will run the `chrome.history.search` API call and either *resolve* with the history items, or *reject* with the error message.

The point of a Promise is that you can use `.then()` on it, chaining the calls.

Let's also promisify `chrome.history.getVisits` (note, it takes a history item, since we want to ):

```
function getVisits(historyItem) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    chrome.history.getVisits({url: historyItem.url}, function(visitItems) {
      if(chrome.runtime.lastError) {
        reject(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
      } else {
        resolve({
          historyItem: historyItem, // let's keep track of it
          visitItems: visitItems
        });
      }
    });
  });
}
```

---

So, we have 2 promises that return an array of results. How to [tie them together](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-parallelism-sequencing)?

First, I assume that you don't break the inner loop (so I run "getVisits" in "parallel"). We have `Promise.all` for that. Let's see..

```
historyLastWeek().then(function(historyItems) {
  return Promise.all(
    // map() returns the array of results of applying a function 
    //   to all members of the array
    historyItems.map(getVisits)
  );
}).then(function(results) {
  // results is an array of objects
  results.each(function(result) {
    // here, result.historyItem is the history item,
    //   and result.visitItems is an array of visit items
    /* here goes your code #1 */
    result.visitItems.each(function(visitItem) {
      /* here goes your "Do something that depends on the first function" code */
    });
    /* here goes your code #2 */
  });
  /* here goes your code #3 */
}).catch(function(errorMsg) {
  // oh noes
});
```

If you need to do something after code #3, then you'll need to promisify that last function as well, and add another `.then()`.

---

This code has the unfortunate property: since JavaScript is not lazy, `all()` will collect all the results in a single, monolithic 2-dimensional array before any of your code is executed, and you can't interrupt the inner loop early.

You can modify this to [execute sequentially](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/#toc-creating-sequences), instead of collecting the array and then processing it.

```
historyLastWeek().then(function(historyItems) {
  return historyItems.reduce(function(sequence, historyItem) {
    return sequence.then(function() {
      return getVisits(historyItem);
    ).then(function(result) {
      // here, result.historyItem is the history item,
      //   and result.visitItems is an array of visit items
      /* here goes your code #1 */
      result.visitItems.each(function(visitItem) {
        /* here goes your "Do something that depends on the first function" code */
      });
      /* here goes your code #2 */
      // Gotta return some promise
      return Promise.resolve();
    });
  }, Promise.resolve());
}).then(function() {
  /* here goes your code #3 */
}).catch(function(errorMsg) {
  // oh noes
});
```

See the link above for an explanation of how all of that works.

It's debatable if it's easier or cleaner than non-Promise code, but at least it's an alternative to manual chaining of callbacks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. However my brain just exploded. I think it will take days for me to understand it all. Until I figure it all, I won't be able to mark as accepted answer, but as soon as I can, I say if it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support versions of Chrome before 32, where the promises were introduced, the only thing you can do is move the code `2` and `3` into the inner callback:

```
function (historyItems) {
    var lastItemIndex = historyItems.length - 1;
    for (var i = 0; i <= lastItemIndex; ++i) {
       chrome.history.getVisits({url: historyItems[i].url}, function(visitItems) {
            // 1
            for (var j = 0; j < visitItems.length; ++j) {
                //Do something that depends on the first function
            }
            // 2
            ......................
            if (i == lastItemIndex) {
                // 3
                ......................
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: That's.. Not the _only_ thing. Promises seem to be the perfect instrument in this situation.

Comment: Also, [citation needed] for even "a lot of people use Chrome 2 major versions behind"

Comment: Ok. I think I'll add a promise-based solution later today, it's good to practice that a bit.

Comment: @Xan, BTW, [netmarketshare](https://www.netmarketshare.com/browser-market-share.aspx?qprid=2&qpcustomd=0) lists Chrome 18-31 at 3%, [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/usage_table.php) lists Chrome 1-31 at 1%. This is a tremendous amount of people, hundreds of thousands or even millions. That's why I still mostly use stuff that works in v31.

Comment: ..that I, personally, would not care about. Support back that far (for a new extension!) is madness, and setting a minimum Chrome version will prevent disappointment.

Comment: If they want things to work, they can upgrade their browser.